# The flux of the vector field $u = x \hat{\imath} + y \hat{\jmath} + z \hat{k}$ through the surface of the ellipsoid

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The flux of the vector field $u = x \hat{\imath} + y \hat{\jmath} + z \hat{k}$ flowing out through the surface of the ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$ , $a>b>c>0$.

I was trying with the Stokes theorem $\int_{C} F.dr = \int \int _{S} (\nabla \times F). \hat{n} ds$ but calculating $\nabla \times F $ I get zero and also if I take $C :$ the projection of the ellipsoid onto say $x-y$ plane , then $C: \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}  =1$.and compute $\int_{C} F.dr$ I too get zero?

I ma uanble to identify the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the divergence theorem. Let $M$ be the solid ellipsoid, so $\partial M$ is its surface. Then
$$\iint_{\partial M} u\cdot dA = \iiint_M \nabla\cdot u\, dV$$

The divergence $\nabla\cdot u=3$ everywhere, so it's 3 times the volume of the ellipsoid. The volume of an ellipsoid is given by $\frac{4}{3}\pi abc$, so the flux is $4\pi abc$.